# Reading from two columns into variables

Tags: c, input

I'm writing a C program that takes an input file and stores it. The input file has two columns, with an integer in the first and a string in the second, like so:

```
    12  apple
    17  frog
    20  grass
```

I've tried using fgets to take an entire line as a string then break it apart using scanf but I'm getting lots of issues. I have searched quite a lot but haven't found anything that answers my question, but sorry if I missed something obvious.
This is the code that I've been trying:

```
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
    {
        scanf(line, "%d\t%s", &key, value);
        insert(key, value, newdict);
    }
```

Comment: tried using fscanf("%d %s", ..) ??

Comment: are you reading input from user or a file?

Comment: or use strtok() and parse the result

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "getting lots of issues"? What issues do you have? Compilation errors? Linker errors? Runtime crashes? If errors please provide them, if crashes have you run your program in a debugger? And most importantly, please show us the code!

Comment: I've tried fscanf but then I started getting segfaults for some reason. I'm reading from a file.

Answer (score 2):

Let's have a quick go at doing with [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) since someone mentioned it. Let's imagine your file is called `file.txt` and has the following contents:

```
10 aaa 
20 bbb 
30 ccc
```

This is how we can parse it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINES 10 // parse a maximum of 10 lines
#define MAX_LINE_SIZE 50       // parse a maximum of 50 chars per line

int main ()
{
    FILE* fh = fopen("file.txt", "r"); // open the file

    char temp[MAX_LINE_SIZE]; // some buffer storage for each line

    // storage for MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINES integers
    int  d_out[MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINES];

    // storage for MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINES strings each MAX_LINE_SIZE chars long
    char s_out[MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINES][MAX_LINE_SIZE];

    // i is a special variable that tells us if we're parsing a number or a string (0 for num, 1 for string)
    // di and si are indices to keep track of which line we're currently handling
    int i = 0, di = 0, si = 0;

    while (fgets(temp, MAX_LINE_SIZE, fh) && di < MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINES) // read the input file and parse the string
    {
        temp[strlen(temp) -1] = '\0'; // get rid of the newline in the buffer

        char* c = strtok(temp, " ");  // set the delimiters

        while(c != NULL)
        {
            if (i == 0) // i equal to 0 means we're parsing a number
            {
                i = 1; // next we'll parse a string, let's indicate that
                sscanf(c, "%d", &d_out[di++]);
            }
            else // i must be 1 parsing a string
            {
                i = 0; // next we'll parse a number
                sprintf(s_out[si++], "%s", c);
            }
            c = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        printf("%d %s\n", d_out[di -1], s_out[si - 1]); // print what we've extracted
    }

    fclose(fh);

    return 0;
}
```

This will extract the contents from the file and store them in respective arrays, we then print them and get back our original contents:

```
$ ./a.out 
10 aaa 
20 bbb 
30 ccc
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying this now. Yeah the first part is being stored as an integer and the second as a char array.

Comment: Just updated my code to include arrays in which the contents are stored, not sure if you've seen it.

Comment: If you've got any questions please ask :)

Comment: In my opinion this code is just too complicated for such a simple task. Usage of *strtok* and then *sscanf* is redundant. The *sscanf* is enough, as it can parse complex input data according to given format. It doesn't require pure data tokens on its input, pre-extracted by *strtok*. What's more, *fgets* can be replaced by *getline* which is now standardized in POSIX (since 2008). It does the memory allocation for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
fgets (name, 100, stdin);
```

`100` is the max length of the buffer. You should adjust it as per your need.

Use:

```
scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", name);
```

The `[]` is the scanset character. `[^\n]` tells that while the input is *not* a newline (`'\n'`) take input. Then with the `%*c` it reads the newline character from the input buffer (which is not read), and the `*` indicates that this read in input is discarded (assignment suppression), as you do not need it, and this newline in the buffer does not create any problem for next inputs that you might take.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be that you are reading from the file *twice*. First with `fgets` and then with `scanf`. You will probably not get an errors from the compiler in your use of `scanf`, but should be getting warnings as you use `line` for the format string and the other arguments does not match the format. It would also be pretty obvious if you checked the return value from `scanf`, as it returns the number of successfully scanned items. Your call would most likely return zero (or minus one when you have hit end of file).

You should be using `sscanf` instead to parse the line you read with `fgets`.

See e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for the different `scanf` variants.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by using [sscanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) (with the support of [getline](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline)) like below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    /* tokens bags */
    char tok_str[255];
    int tok_int;

    fp = fopen("./file.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    /* Reads the line from the stream. */
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        /* Scans the character string pointed by line, according to given format. */
        sscanf(line, "%d\t%s", &tok_int, tok_str);
        printf("%d-%s\n", tok_int, tok_str);
    }

    if (line)
        free(line);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Or, even simpler. You could use [fscanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) (with the support of [feof](http://linux.die.net/man/3/feof)) and replace the while loop shown above (along with some other redundant code cleanups) with the following one:

```
    /* Tests the end-of-file indicator for the stream. */
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        /* Scans input from the file stream pointer. */
        fscanf(fp,"%d\t%s\n",&tok_int, tok_str);
        printf("%d-%s\n", tok_int, tok_str);
    }
```

Assuming that your file contains following lines (where single line format is *number[tab]string[newline]*):

```
12  apple
17  frog
20  grass
```

the output will be:

```
12-apple
17-frog
20-grass
```